# Podspec for a private embedded OS X framework?

Tags: macos, frameworks, cocoapods

I have an OS X library that’s packaged as a private framework (a framework that’s embedded inside the app bundle). The usual way to include such framework into an app project is to link the app against the framework and copy the built framework into the `Frameworks` subfolder in the app bundle (using the Copy Files build phase). Now I want to distribute this library using CocoaPods. What do I write in the podspec to build and copy the framework? Is this scenario even supported by CocoaPods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s currently a [requested feature](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1024) in the CocoaPods codebase.